Warnings showing in terminal but yellow squiggles not showing in the code
VSCode is not showing yellow squiggles in the code, but warnings are shown in the terminal.
macOS version : macOS Sonoma version 14.5
Visual Studio Code:
Version: 1.86.2 (Universal)
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:42:13.651Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 23.5.0
Tried modifying user settings, and .eslintrc.cjs but nothing seems to work
Code with no yellow underline
My issue is similar to the one below, but the fixes suggested did not really work
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116305#issuecomment-780099359

Please do not duplicate the tag information in your post title. The tag system works extremely well here and doesn't need help. Needlessly repeating the tags in the title is just unnecessary noise and clutter.

potentially a problemmatcher pattern issue...?
